# after i update my notification count, the box has an extra space. how can i remove this?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

better to add an image to show what i mean. I want to get rid of the extra space on the left of the number that appear, after i click on a notification to remove it from my count of notifications.

[image: after]

[image: befopre]

here is my code.

```
<?php echo "<span id='notification_count'>".trim(count($notifications))."</span>;"?>
```

this is the ajax which will mark the notification as read and update the count.

```
<script>
function mark_notification_read(id){
$.post('../php/notification/mark_notification_read.php',{id:id},function(data){
data = $.trim(data);
    if(data == 'success'){
    notification_count();
    }else{
    alert(data);
    }
});
}
function notification_count(){
$.post('../php/notification/notification_count.php',{},function(data){
    $('#notification_count').text(data);
});
}
</script>
```

this is the text that gets inserted into the new count from notification_count.php

```
$notifications=show_notifications($_SESSION['user_id']);
echo trim(count($notifications));
```

Comment: not sure if it makes a difference but try .html(data);

Comment: awesome, thanks! that worked. if you want credit,for this answer, submit as an answer and i will check it

Comment: The reason .html works instead of .text is because using .text is converting the string to use `&nbsp;` which is causing your space problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really glad it helped

```
 .html(data)
```